# Why React useState returns different Value when accessed from a different component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Consider this example,

component.js

```
    ...
    const tableInstance = useTableInstance(); // Inital tableInstance.getRows().length = 0

    const tableAction = [{
      iconClass: 'add-icon',
      execute: () => {
       console.log('Total Rows Inside Execute', tableInstance.getRows().length); --> 1
       tableInstance.addRow();
       // State is changed. Component is rerendered.
      }
    }]
    ...
    console.log('Total Rows Outside Execute', tableInstance.getRows().length); --> 2
    return (<Toolbar tableActions={tableAction} />
             <Table instance={tableInstance}/>)
```

generic-toolbar.ts

```
...

return toolbarAction.map(ele => <span className={ele.iconClass} onClick={()=> ele.execute()} />
...
```

Is this correct way ? I am following any any anti-pattern. When this approach is taken at generic way, in some components it works, However in some.

Console 1 & 2 returns different values.

Console 1 prints the initially set value and Console 2 prints the latest updated value.
This fails only in certain cases which I am yet to pin point.

Thanks in advance for any solutions.

Comment: That makes sense. Console 2 prints on re-render. Console 1 prints before state updates. addRow() likely sets state, triggers re-render, and console 2 logs on next render.

Comment: In all the subsequent logs, only console 2 provides the correct value. console 1 still prints the initial value.